# Return how many terms are necessary entering a level of precision, e.g .001, to come within the specified precision of the value of PI?

Tags: java, pi

**Problem:** *Interactively enter a level of precision, e.g., .001, and then report how many terms are necessary for each of these estimates to come within the specified precision of the value of pi.*

**My Solution So Far:**
Current result does not terminate. The `PIEstimator` class driver is given. The problem lies inside the `PIEstimates` class. Some specific questions that I have:

How do you calculate [Wallis PI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product) and [Leibniz PI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80) in code? The ways for calculating each arithmetically for Wallis is:

pi/4 = (2/3)*(4/3)*(4/5)*(6/5)*(6/7)*(8/7)*(8/9)*... 
and for Leibniz:

pi/4 = (1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9 ...)

Is the current logic of doing this code correct so far? Using a while loop to check if the respective PI calculation is within the limits, with a for loop inside continuing to run until the while requirements are met. Then there is a count that returns the number of times the loop repeated.

For .001, for example, how many terms does it take for each of these formulas to reach a value between 3.14059.. and 3.14259...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PiEstimator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Wallis vs Leibnitz:");
    System.out.println("Terms needed to estimate pi");
    System.out.println("Enter precision sought");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    double tolerance = scan.nextDouble();
    PiEstimates e = new PiEstimates(tolerance);
    System.out.println("Wallis: " + e.wallisEstimate());
    System.out.println("Leibnitz: " + e.leibnitzEstimate());
    }
}

public class PiEstimates {
    double n = 0.0;
    double upperLim = 0;
    double lowerLim = 0;

    public PiEstimates(double tolerance) {
        n = tolerance;
        upperLim = Math.PI+n;
        lowerLim = Math.PI-n;
    }

    public double wallisEstimate() {
        double wallisPi = 4;
        int count = 0;
        while(wallisPi > upperLim || wallisPi < lowerLim) {
            for (int i = 3; i <= n + 2; i += 2) {
                wallisPi = wallisPi * ((i - 1) / i) * ((i + 1) / i);
            }
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public double leibnitzEstimate() {
        int b = 1;
        double leibnizPi = 0;
        int count = 0;
        while(leibnizPi > upperLim || leibnizPi < lowerLim) {
            for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i += 2) {
                leibnizPi += (4/i - 4/i+2);
            }
            b = -b;
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: What was the purpose of the variable b? It serves no purpose?

Answer (score 0):

At least one mistake in `wallisEstimate`

```
for (int i = 3; i <= n + 2; i += 2) {
```

should be `count` instead of `n`:

```
for (int i = 3; i <= count + 2; i += 2) {
```

... but still then the algorithm is wrong. This would be better:

```
public double wallisEstimate() {
    double wallisPi = 4;
    int count = 0;
    int i = 3;
    while(wallisPi > upperLim || wallisPi < lowerLim) {
        wallisPi = wallisPi * ((i - 1) / i) * ((i + 1) / i);
        count++;
        i += 2;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Similarly, for the Leibniz function:

```
public double leibnitzEstimate() {
    double leibnizPi = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int i = 1;
    while(leibnizPi > upperLim || leibnizPi < lowerLim) {
        leibnizPi += (4/i - 4/i+2);
        count++;
        i += 4;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Leibnitz, I think the inner loop should only run `count` number of times:

```
for (int i = 1; i < count; i += 2) {
            leibnizPi += (4/i - 4/i+2);
        }
```

If it runs 1000 times every time you can't know when pi was in range.

Answer (score 0):

If the while loops don't terminate, then they don't approach PI.

*Wallis:* `pi/4 = (2/3)(4/3)(4/5)(6/5)(6/7)(8/7)(8/9)*...`

The while loop would restart the for loop at `i = 3` which would keep adding the same sequence of terms, rather than progressing along with the pattern.

Here's a draft of an alternative solution (no pun intended) based on the pattern of terms.
As you see, the numerators repeat, except for the 2. The divisors repeat aswell, but offset from the numerators: they increment in an alternating fashion.

This way you can actually count each individual terms, instead of pairs of them.

```
public double wallisEstimate() {
    double wallisPi = 1; 
    int count = 0;
    double numerator = 2;
    double divisor = 3;
    while(wallisPi > upperLim || wallisPi < lowerLim) {
        wallisPi *= numerator / divisor;
        if ( count++ & 1 == 0 )
            numerator+=2;
        else
            divisor+=2;
    }
    return count;
}
```

There is one more change to make, and that is in the initialisation of `upperLim` and `lowerLim`. The algorithm approaches `PI/2`, so:

```
    upperLim = (Math.PI + tolerance)/2;
    lowerLim = (Math.PI - tolerance)/2;
```

*Leibniz:* `pi/4 = (1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9 ...)`

Here the for loop is also unwanted: at best, you will be counting increments of 2000 terms at a time.

The pattern becomes obvious if you write it like this:

> 1/1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 ...

The divisor increments by 2 for every next term.

```
public double leibnitzEstimate() {
    double leibnizPi = 0;
    int divisor = 1;
    int count = 0;
    while(leibnizPi > upperLim || leibnizPi < lowerLim) {
        leibnizPi +=  1.0 / divisor;
        divisor = -( divisor + 2 );  
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

The update of `leibnizPi` can also be written like this:

```
        leibnizPi +=  sign * 1.0 / divisor;
        divisor += 2;
        sign = -sign;
```

which is more clear, takes one more variable and one more instruction.

An update to the `upperLim` and `lowerLim` must be made here aswell: the algorithm approaches PI/4 (different from Leibniz!), so:

```
    upperLim = (Math.PI + tolerance)/4;
    lowerLim = (Math.PI - tolerance)/4;
```